# msExchDelegateListBL attribute - The attribute cannot be modified because it is owned by the system

Tags: powershell

When attempting to clear `msExchDelegateListBL` for AD User then I got the following the error message.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity "User01" -Properties * | set-aduser -clear msExchDelegateListBL
```

Message :

```
set-aduser : The attribute cannot be modified because it is owned by the system
At line:1 char:49
+ ... ity "User01" -Properties * | set-aduser -clear msExchDelegateListBL
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=User01...,DC=corp:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8369,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

LAST UPDATE :

```
  $userDN = Get-ADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq $true -and sAMAccountName -like "TEST*") -or (Enabled -eq $true -and sAMAccountName -like "PROD*")} -SearchBase "OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=local" -SearchScope Subtree -Properties *  |select-object distinguishedname,samaccountname
  foreach($userToClean in $userDN) {

  $delegates = Get-ADUser $userToClean.samaccountname -Properties msExchDelegateListBL |  select -ExpandProperty msExchDelegateListBL
  Write-Host “======================================================”
  write-host “List of Delegated accounts that are backlinked:” $Delegates
  Write-Host “======================================================”
  foreach ($delegate in $delegates) {
  Set-ADUser $delegate -Remove @{msExchDelegateListLink = "$($userToClean.distinguishedname)"}
  }
  Write-Host “======================================================”
  Write-Host “If the following get-aduser cmdlet searching for backlinds is empty, then all delegated backlinks have been removed”
  Get-ADUser $userToClean.samaccountname -Properties msExchDelegateListBL |  select -ExpandProperty msExchDelegateListBL
  Write-Host “======================================================”

  }
```

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do it like this. The `msExchDelegateListBL` attribute is adjusted by the system after a user is removed from the `msExchDelegateListLink` of the delegate. [Here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2018/03/31/removing-orphaned-populated-msexchangedelegatelinklist-and-msexchangedelegatelinklistbl-automapping-attributes-2/) is a good read about that, including PowerShell code. (scroll down to `To remove all BLs all at once`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I want to clear msExchDelegateListBL attribute for all enabled users in OU. (AD TEST Environment).  I have updatd my script above my message. Am I correct ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot test this myself. Although I would change the top line into `$userDN = Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -SearchBase "OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=local" -SearchScope Subtree | Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -match '^(TEST|PROD)' }`, it looks OK to me. Maybe also, while testing, add switch `-WhatIf` to the `Set-ADUser` cmdlet

Comment: ok it works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks for letting us know this worked. I have now posted it as answer, so that this will not be "just another unanswered question" because I'm sure other people may be struggling with this aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The msExchDelegateListBL attribute is adjusted by the system after a user is removed from (or added to) the `msExchDelegateListLink` of the delegate.

When users are granted permission to a shared mailbox, the default behaviour of automapping means that the shared mailbox has `msExchDelegateListLink` set to the DN of the users, and the backlink property (`msExchDelegateLinkListBL` hidden in AD by default) on each user is populated with the DN of the shared mailbox. Whenever the link attribute is updated, the backlink is automatically updated.

I found a [good read](https://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2018/03/31/removing-orphaned-populated-msexchangedelegatelinklist-and-msexchangedelegatelinklistbl-automapping-attributes-2/) about that, including PowerShell code.

For your question I suggest to scroll down to `To remove all BLs all at once` chapter and adapt the code in there to suit your needs as you have done in your edit.

Personally, I would change the top line in your code into

```
$userDN = Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -SearchBase "OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=local" -SearchScope Subtree | 
Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -match '^(TEST|PROD)' }
```

since user properties `SamAccountName` and `DistinguishedName` are returned by the `Get-ADUSer` cmdlet by default.